# Render updated document to ejs page mongoose node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

I have an app where users can create an account and update their information after creation. I am able to save the updated document to the database when users input new information on the edit page, however, when I redirect them to the user panel, the old information is still being displayed. I believe that it has something to do with the session that gets created on login because the updated information only shows once the user logs out and logs back in.
This is my edit page:

```
<%- include('partials/header') %>

<% if(user.firstName.endsWith("s")) { %>
<h1 class="dashboard-title"><%=user.firstName + "' Account"%></h1>
<% } else { %>
<h1 class="dashboard-title"><%=user.firstName + "'s Account"%></h1>
<% } %>

<!-- Action Buttons -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <a href="/logout" class="dashboard-btn">
        <h5>Logout <i class="fas fa-door-open"></i></h5>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <a href="/edit" class="dashboard-btn">
        <h5>Edit <i class="fas fa-edit"></i></h5>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<br>

<!-- Information -->
<div class="container">
  <form class="" action="/edit" method="post">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <label class="col-form-label col-md-1" for="firstName">First Name:</label>
      <div class="form-group col-md-7">
        <input name="firstName" class="form-control" type="text" value="<%=user.firstName%>" >
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <label class="col-form-label col-md-1" for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
      <div class="form-group col-md-7">
        <input name="lastName" class="form-control" type="text" value="<%=user.lastName%>" >
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <label class="col-form-label col-md-1" for="email">Email:</label>
      <div class="form-group col-md-7">
        <input name="email" class="form-control" type="text" value="<%=user.username%>" readonly>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <label class="col-form-label col-md-1" for="phone">Phone:</label>
      <div class="form-group col-md-7">
        <input name="phone" class="form-control" type="text" value="<%=user.phoneNumber%>" >
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <label class="col-form-label col-md-1" for="address">Address:</label>
      <div class="form-group col-md-7">
        <input name="address" class="form-control" type="text" value="<%=user.personalInfo.address%>" >
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <label class="col-form-label col-md-1" for="coverage">Coverage:</label>
      <div class="form-group col-md-7">
        <input name="coverage" class="form-control" type="text" value="<%=user.coverage%>" >
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <label class="col-form-label col-md-1" for="paymentPlan">Payment:</label>
      <div class="form-group col-md-7">
        <input name="paymentPlan" class="form-control" type="text" value="<%=user.paymentPlan%>">
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <button class="btn register-btn" type="submit">Submit Changes</button>
  </form>
</div>

<%- include('partials/footer') %>
```

And app.js to handle the post requests to edit route:

```
app.get("/user-panel", function(req, res) {
    if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
      res.render("user-panel", {
        user: req.user
      });
    } else {
      res.redirect('/login');
    }
  });

  app.get("/edit", function(req, res) {
    if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
      res.render("edit", {
        user: req.user
      });
    } else {
      res.redirect("/login");
    }
  });

  app.post("/edit", function(req, res) {
    const email = req.user.username;
    const firstName = req.body.firstName;
    const lastName = req.body.lastName;
    const phone = req.body.phone;

    User.findOne({username: email}, function(err, foundUser) {
      if(err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        if (foundUser) {
          foundUser.firstName = firstName;
          foundUser.save();
          res.redirect("/user-panel");
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

Any ideas on how I can get the server to respond with the updated info without having to log out the user?

Comment: I believe you need to do another query to the database when you call `res.redirect("/user-panel");`. so inside `/user-panel` query the database so it renders with new values. Let me know if you need me to explain more

Comment: Yes thank you I was able to do this with this function on every route:  ``function queryUserDb(req, res) {
    User.findOne({username: req.user.username}, function(err, foundUser) {
      if(err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        if(foundUser) {
          res.render(req.url.substring(1), {
            user: foundUser
          });
        }
      }
    });

} ``

Answer (score 1):

I want to touch on a few things.

1. to answer your question, you need to query the database again upon redirect. like so:

you need to pass the `email` value back to the original `user-panel` function:

```
res.redirect("/user-panel?username=" + email);
```

then, you have to query the database again, like so:

```
    app.get("/user-panel", authCheck, function(req, res) {
    let email = req.query.email

    User.findOne({username: email}, function(err, foundUser) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            if (foundUser) {
            foundUser.firstName = firstName;
            foundUser.save();
            res.render("user-panel", {
                user: req.user
            });
            }
        }
    });
        
        
  });
```

2. You should try not to use authentication logic within each function, rather have it as a seperate function and import it as `middleware`. Makes it cleaner. I've rewritten it for you.

```js
    function authCheck(req, res, next) {
        if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
            next()
        } else {
            res.redirect('/login');
        }
    
    }
```

now within any new function you create (within this file), you can just use the function `authCheck()` as middleware:

```
app.get('/', authCheck, (req, res) => {
```

Comment: I was able to render the updated values with your suggestions, however I am not querying the username in the URL. Instead, I created a function that accepts req and res and queries the database if there is a user, and I added this function to every route because I found that if you only query the database on the user panel, then only the user panel page gets updated. Since I am using the user's first name to render on the navigation bar when users are logged in, I needed to check the database on every route.

Comment: @FabrizioHenriquez awesome! glad it could help, and your way sounds great, better than my way actually. More functional.